# JQuery - How i can save list in the cookie

Tags: jquery

**I followed this tutorial**

http://fricardo.com/manipulando-cookies-com-jquery/

**and i saving my list in the cookie:**

```
jQuery.cookie('matrizTela', vList, {expires: 7});
```

**but, if i show in my console.log my cookie:**

```
console.log(jQuery.cookie('matrizTela'));
```

**my return is:**

```
,[object Object]
```

Why my return having the "," and dont print my object list ?

**PS:** my vList is a matrix of the DOM Object

**What i need?**

I want to save an matrix(a list of DOM Object within the VLIST) and then retrieve the VLIST through this cookie and manipulate the data again.

**My Problem?**

Having one comma in my return.

Comment: How are you creating `vList`?

Comment: "vList.push(saveList[tamanho]);" vList is a matriz

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the plugin is internally calling `.toString()` on the object you want to store.

If you want to store it correctly I suggest you do something like

```
jsonList = JSON.stringify(vList);

jQuery.cookie('matrizTela', jsonList, {expires: 7});
```

Witch will convert your object in a json string, for example:

```
JSON.stringify([1,2,3]) // "[1,2,3]"
```

Then, you could retrieve it like:

```
jsonList = jQuery.cookie('matrizTela');

console.log( JSON.parse(jsonList) );
```

Comment: My problem is the comma, i don't know where coming comma

Comment: my code is huge and very complex, I think easier to explain to you my goal:  

I want to save an matrix(a list of DOM Object within the VLIST) and then retrieve the VLIST through this cookie and manipulate the data again.

Comment: Then the comma isn't an issue, the issue is that you should serialize (like the example in my answer o any other way you like) your object before you store it, and deserialize it after you get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store complex objects in a cookie. You need to serialize them; try JSON.

Comment: is not possible to save a list in a cookie?
but where this coming this comma (,)